# Add attachment button to a custom list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list, infopath

I have SharePoint custom list customized with info path 2013. I need to have two attachment on it. Can I achieve this out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add the attachment buttons when editing the forms in InfoPath 2013. It is the SharePoint list form. It is by design.

You can upload multiple files by one attachment button in the list forms.

The attachment buttons can be added in the blank form in InfoPath.

[image]